# ReactiveUI : Binding lost after exception in property setter

Tags: reactiveui

In a  WinForms ReactiveUI ViewModel I have a property with a property setter that can throw an ArgumentException:

```
public string Foo
    {
        get { return _foo; }
        set
        {
            if (value == "ERR" ) throw new ArgumentException("simulate an error");
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _foo, value);
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Set Foo to {0}", _foo));
        }
    } 
 private string _foo;
```

In View the property Foo is bind to a textbox uiFoo:

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Foo, v => v.uiFoo.Text);
```

Binding works properly (as shown by the output of the setter’s Debug.WriteLine).
But after typing “ERR” which throws ArgumentException the binding no longer works.

What solution do I have to bring back (or keep)  binding in working state after the exceptions in setter ?

Comment: You might try to catch and handle the exception somewhere before it hits the uppermost layers of the framework. How can a setter normally raise an exception?

Comment: I'd recommend against throwing exceptions in a setter. If a value is invalid the setter should just return, without setting the value to the backing field

Comment: Throwing exceptions from a setter is a bad pattern. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/property

Comment: X AVOID throwing exceptions from property getters.+

Property getters should be simple operations and should not have any preconditions. If a getter can throw an exception, it should probably be redesigned to be a method. Notice that this rule does not apply to indexers, where we do expect exceptions as a result of validating the arguments.

Comment: @GeoffreyHuntley claims you shouldn't throw exceptions from setters. This does not match the MS guidelines. They say to not throw exceptions from getters. For setters, they assume they can throw as implied by "✔️ DO preserve the previous value if a property setter throws an exception."

Answer (score -1):

As we've mentioned in the comments on your question, exceptions inside property getter or setters is a **BIG NO, NO**.

Here are two solutions available to you: Either handle the invalid value when you try to read it or use a setter method. I would much prefer the latter; especially as you're throwing an `ArgumentException`, which should only be used when arguments are supplied. (Breaking this rule might be confusing for the consumer of the code: "Why am I getting an ArgumentException when I'm not calling any functions?")

Here's a way to do it:

```
public string Foo { get; private set; }

public void SetFoo(string value)
{
    if(value == "invalid value")
        thrown new ArgumentException($"{nameof(Foo)} can't be set to '{value}'", nameof(value));

    Foo = value;
}
```